# How to ask current internship employer about potential full time employment?

Tags: interviewing, negotiation

I have interned full time at company A for the past two summers and have worked part time for them during the school year. I am currently in the final interview process of applying for a position at company B.

Keep in mind, I have a fairly good relationship with company A. They have a very relaxed work environment and it has been fun interning with them, but they are a very small company and so there may not be too much room to move up. On the other hand, company B is a large company that will probably have the resources to maybe offer a little more than company A. Also company B is located in a preferred location.

How should I ask my current employer (company A) if they would hire me for a full time position when I graduate? How do I subtly indicate that I am applying at another company? Also, during my final interview at company B, should I indicate that I have a good relationship with A and that I could envision an offer from them soon?

Answer (score 3):

Unsupported personal opinion; some folks will certainly disagree:

1) Just ask. Recruiting and evaluating good candidates is a major part of why companies run internships.

2) Don't bother telling them you are interviewing at A. They should assume this, and saying it may come across as more adversarial than you want it to be. At most, *maybe* say you're starting to interview generally, and would like to apply here too; see (1).

3) If you get an offer from A before you get one from B, then you could tell B that you've got the offer but would rather work for them, so if they are going to make you an offer they should hurry up before you have to say yes to A... But "you could envision an offer" is an extremely weak statement even if it feels significant to you, and I don't think it's a useful card to play, for the same reasons as (2).

Answer (score 0):

1) Approach manager of A whom you report, and express your interest. Emphasize on how much you value the Company A, Specify what are the unique things that you like about company, and how can you contribute to Company A and how can you help Company A.

2) And also be honest with manager A and tell that you have applied positions with other Companies. You can say like "Even though I have applied positions at other Companies, I am keen to work for Company A. If I got offer from Company A, I prefer Company A over other Companies.

3) For Company B, You need not tell Proactively that the fact you are considering the offer from Company A. However if they ask You can reveal the fact that you are Considering offer from Company A. But you can assure that if you don't hear from Company A so and so date, and if you have the offer from B you can choose B.